# Ldap loggin in spring with log4j xml

Tags: java, spring, ldap, log4j

I have a LDAP Basic Auth config in the next Web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>mathematicians</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ldap-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>Rol por defecto de la aplicacion mathematicians</description>
    <role-name>mathematicians</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Is the only configuration that I have (and tomcat configuration), and works fine, the problem is that I need show in the log file (configure with log4j xml) when have auth problems; ie: the user or password is wrong, or the connection with ldap fails.

Comment: R u talking about logging in file using `log4j` or do u want to display error in jsp page with log in file, on failure of authentication ? Provided info in question is very less & unclear. Improve ur question & give specific details about what u want exactly ?

Comment: Im sorry, I like to show in my log file the auth errors.

Comment: When u r calling `ldapContext.search(LDAP_GROUP, "mail=" + emailId, constraints);` to look in LDAP for the given `emailId` or `userName`, u get the data in `NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer` form. From this u can  check whether this enum has data using `answer.hasMore()`. If u get the required data then login succces otherwise give a call to `LOGGER.fatal("Your Message");` Lets have a try & let me know is this works for u ?

Comment: When I start the application, it shows a popup window to auth (Basic Auth), and i have no checks in my code, the ldap do it all.

Comment: Exactly. Bcoz u r using `<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>`. If u want a custom login form then u have to use `<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>`. Check out [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/secure-web-application-java)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need the form auth, I only need show in my log file or debug console the LDAP errors with auth basic.

Comment: Then follow the 3rd comment. Write code to check valid credentials & log the messages in file. Otherwise, how would u know the invalid login has been done & it's time to log error msg ? In my case, I hv created class which look for the given credentials in LDAP & return the status of login.

Comment: I don't use ldapContext.search , spring do all automatic. I thought that add at log4j.xml something like :  
<logger name="org.springframework.security.ldap">
  <level value="trace" />
 </logger>
it works...